# Hidden form parameter pass to controller

Tags: laravel, forms

how can I pass the $member->id to my controller. {{$member->username}} should only be shown.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    @if(isset($members))
            @foreach($members as $member)  
                {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'store.exclusion')) !!}  
                    // $member->id should go to the controller methode
                    {{$member->username}}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name = "submitbutton" value = "save">Ausschließen</button>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            @endforeach 
        </div>
    @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to write the parameter into the array part. I want to have the parameter in a hidden form field. Is that possible?

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="{{ $member->id }} />
```

Then in your controller use it via:

```
$member_id = request()->input('member_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hidden input field inside your form which would look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="{{ $member->id }}>
```

Then in your controller method you could simply call it like this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $memberId = $request->memer_id
}
```

Dont forget to add the member_id in your fillable array in your model.